# Show a video twice, but in full screen on a second display

Tags: multiple-monitors

Here is what I want: I open a video on my main monitor (I do not care about what player I should use) and I want to display it on my second monitor, in fullscreen.

My graphic card is a Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS.

Comment: So that the video is playing across both screens? Or so that it just takes up all of the secondary screen?

Comment: Anything that can work for now, I search for hours...

Comment: What OS are you on?

Answer (score 2):

Look for "Full Screen Video" or "Video Mirroring" in the nVidia control panel. This should do what you're looking for (take a video that's playing on your main screen, like youtube, and display a copy of it on the second monitor in fullscreen). Note, this is dependent upon the video player using hardware acceleration and a video overlay to render the video (most do these days).

Answer (score 0):

(windows) Just attach your second monitor, enable extended display, open your video file, drag to desired monitor and hit F11.

Caveat: This worked for me in Windows XP SP2. I have not been on a multiple display system since.

Comment: He wants to duplicate the video on the second screen, not move it to the second screen.

Comment: Wasn't apparent from the question, at least to me. I'll leave the answer as is for now because I'm not sure how to do that and I don't want to bother figuring it out if it turns out that the problem was already solved.